# Changing filter type

Tags: tableau-api

My date filter looks like this
[image: my filter]

but i want it to be a dropdown menu like this 
[image]

how do i do it? these are the only formats i can select 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

When creating the filter you must choose discrete dates instead of continuous. then you will have the option to display it as a dropdown menu.

Answer (score 1):

This type of filter looks like this null column to add so drop down is not shown.so update the year values and got the year in **show filter** and then **select the single value drop down**. and edit the name in select year to show the drop down menu.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Littly will work, 
One more suggestion is to create a small calculated field called year of Date - 
which says -

```
YEAR(Date)
```

Put this new field in the filters and click on show quick filters and then you can select drop down and get the desired result.

The reason why this works is that, your field is now either a String column or an Integer column, it will be easily converted to drop down as compared to dates.